# select2 json tags input

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I work with select2 plugin. tags input worked like this :

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="tags" value="tag1,tag2" style="width: 400px;">
```

JS:

```
$('#tags').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    createSearchChoice: function (term) {
        return {
            id: $.trim(term),
            text: $.trim(term) + ' (new tag)'
        };
    },
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/444cr',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    },

    // Take default tags from the input value
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];

        function splitVal(string, separator) {
            var val, i, l;
            if (string === null || string.length < 1) return [];
            val = string.split(separator);
            for (i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i = i + 1) val[i] = $.trim(val[i]);
            return val;
        }

        $(splitVal(element.val(), ",")).each(function () {
            data.push({
                id: this,
                text: this
            });
        });

        callback(data);
    },

    // Some nice improvements:

    // max tags is 3
    maximumSelectionSize: 3,

    // override message for max tags
    formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) {
        return "Max tags is only " + limit;
    }
});
```

Files Json Ouput:

```
[{"id":"tag1","text":"tag1"},{"id":"tag2","text":"tag2"},{"id":"tag3","text":"tag3"},{"id":"tag4","text":"tag4"}]
```

This Worked, But I have NEW array file like this :

```
["Aus","Bng","Dsa","Ymn","Was","Mip"]
```

with this file select2 not work and not show tags. how do can i edit js for my files?

Worked DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/X6V2s/2/

Not Worked DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/X6V2s/5/

Comment: Your so called `NEW json file` is an array not json...

Comment: @Bhavik: you right. i edited this

Comment: http://drs.url.ph/citynames.php page shows this `[{"Aus"},{"Bng"},{"Dsa"},{"Ymn"},{"Was"},{"Mip"}]` instead of `["Aus","Bng","Dsa","Ymn","Was","Mip"]`

Comment: @Bhavik: fixed! i work With this file.